# Unable to convert a object to a string

Tags: python, pandas

When attempting to convert a column in Python 3 from an object to a string, the code I am using doesn't error, but it also doesn't change the type.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import os
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
import nltk.corpus
import re

#Read in fields
jan = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Sabrina\JIRA\2019\2019_jan.xls')

#Indicate columns for performing tokenization
jan_a = pd.DataFrame(jan, columns= ['Summary'])

#Tokenize columns for text analysis
jan_a['Summary'] = jan_a.apply(lambda column: 
    nltk.word_tokenize(column['Summary']), axis=1)
print(jan_a)
print(jan_a['Summary'].dtypes)

#Convert list to string
jan_a['Summary'].astype('str')
print(jan_a['Summary'].dtypes)
```

The output for both dtypes is object, any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that astype return it as the given type, not change it inplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default behavior is to treat python str as object by default

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(["aa1 bb2 cc3".split(),"aa4 bb5 cc6".split()],columns="col1 col2 col3".split())
>>> 
>>> df
  col1 col2 col3
0  aa1  bb2  cc3
1  aa4  bb5  cc6
>>> df["col1"]
0    aa1
1    aa4
Name: col1, dtype: object
>>>
```

you need to explicit told it that you want string either on creation by adding a `dtype="string"`

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame(["aa1 bb2 cc3".split(),"aa4 bb5 cc6".split()],dtype="string",columns="col1 col2 col3".split())
>>> df2
  col1 col2 col3
0  aa1  bb2  cc3
1  aa4  bb5  cc6
>>> df2["col1"]
0    aa1
1    aa4
Name: col1, dtype: string
>>>
```

or by later transforming it with astype

```
>>> df["col1"].astype("string")
0    aa1
1    aa4
Name: col1, dtype: string
>>>
```

link to the relevant part of the documentation for more detail: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#text-types

Comment: When you say by default, does that mean I am unable to convert it as it is?

Comment: no, the default seem to be that when not explicitly told, treat it like a regular python object, hence object, to need to indicate it that you will be working with string, just as the documentation indicate by adding `dtype="string"` as in the latest update of my example

Comment: Ah ok gotcha, I made the following edits

pd.Series(jan_a['Summary'])
pd.Series(jan_a['Summary']).astype("string")

And the console shows:
    169         """Validate that we only store NA or strings."""
    170         if len(self._ndarray) and not lib.is_string_array(self._ndarray, skipna=True):
--> 171             raise ValueError("StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA")
    172         if self._ndarray.dtype != "object":
    173             raise ValueError(

ValueError: StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA

Comment: I made another update to try explain it better... now it look like you get and error, I'm not a pandas expert, so I'm not sure if I can do more without a working example

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
jan_a['Summary'].astype('str')
```

to

```
jan_a['Summary'] = jan_a['Summary'].astype('string')
```

Comment: Same result unfortunately